# Are continuous periodic functions dense in $L^p(\mathbb{T})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am studying Fourier Series and in it, the fact that $C^0 (\mathbb{T})$ or $C^\infty (\mathbb{T})$ is dense(in the $L^p(\mathbb{T})$ norm, i.e. integral restricted to the domain with one period) in $L^p(\mathbb{T})$ where $1\le p <\infty$ and $\mathbb{T}$ denotes the space of functions on the real line with period $1$(or any real number). However, I can't find a reference which states this fact, all I can find is that $C_c (\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p (\mathbb{R}^n)$ but I don't think this fact implies the above.

For instance, in the below proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for periodic functions, approximation with $C^0(\mathbb{T})$ functions is used.

[image]

Comment: just google "continuous functions dense in L^p"

Comment: @zhw. I can only find continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p$ but I need periodic ones for this theorem.

Comment: If you have a continuous function approximating an $L^p$ function within an $\epsilon/2$, then you can modify the values of the function to become periodic, without changing  the $L^p$ norm by more than another $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: @TrialAndError How can that be done analytically? We need the value at the endpoints of the function to be the same. I don't see how they can be modified without changing the norm.

Comment: @takecare We just went through this in another thread: Approximate in $L^p,$ then cut it off to make it $0$ at the endpoints, which will not disturb the approximation by much.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that functions which vanish at both endpoints of the interval are already periodic.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts How can it be periodic?